# What is the probability that in random $n$-permutation one belongs to the cycle length $k$?

Tags: combinatorics

> Natural numbers are given $ n \ge k> 0 $. What is the probability that in random $n$-permutation one belongs to the cycle length $k$?

I think that probability is:$$\frac{\binom{n}{k-1}(k-1)!(n-k)!}{n!}$$
Because:

$n!$ - all possibilities

$\binom{n}{k-1}$ - choosing things for the cycle

$(k-1)!$ - sorting cycle

$(n-k)!$ - random permutation of the rest of elements allowing any number of cycles
Is this correct?

Comment: Does this give the right answer if $n=k=3$ ?

Comment: It is hard to understand the question without the thoughts in the direction of a solution, and the question is if the guess of the question based on the solution matches indeed the solution. This is objectively the point where this comments starts. The question may be restated as: Let $n, k$ be given. Count all permutations $s$ of the symbols $1,2,3,...,n$ so that $1$ (well, "one" is misleading...) appears in a cycle of length $k$ when $s$ is written as a product of disjoint cycles.  If this is the question, than change the $n$ over $(k-1)$ into  $/n-1)$ over $(k-1)$, since one took the $1$...

Comment: Expanding the binomial and applying dan_fulea's correction makes the entire expression simplify to $1/n$, which interestingly is independent of $k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small correction: I think that the term related to  "choosing things for the cycle" should be  $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ (since $1$ is already in the $k$-cycle!). Therefore the probability is
$$\frac{\binom{n-1}{k-1}(k-1)!(n-k)!}{n!}=\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{n}$$
which is independent of $k$.

For example, if $n=3$, then we have $6$ permutations and for any $k=1,2,3$ the probability is $2/6=1/3$.

For $k=1$: $(\mathbf{1})(2,3)$, $(\mathbf{1})(2)(3)$.

For $k=2$: $(\mathbf{1},2)(3)$, $(\mathbf{1},3)(2)$.

For $k=3$: $(\mathbf{1},2,3)$, $(\mathbf{1},3,2)$.